# In Spark 2.4, Doesn't Spark JDBC allow to specifying Built in function as the partitionColumn?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to change spark version 2.2.1 to 2.4.0
In spark 2.2, Following worked fine.

```
val query = "(select id, myPartitionColumnString from myTable) query"
val splitColumn = "CHECKSUM(myPartitionColumnString)"
spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, query, splitColumn, lowerBound, upperBound, numPartitions, connectionProperties)
```

But In spark 2.4, It cause Error like this

```
User-defined partition column CHECKSUM(myPartitionColumnString) not found in the JDBC relation: struct<id: int, myPartitionColumnString: string>
```

I'm sure CheckSum is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They removed it during introduction of "pass direct SQL query" functionality. Breaking change was introduced in 2.4.0. It was more of a hack, there's no way to achieve this now. You can still get it in 2.3 tho

PS: if somebody finds another way to achieve same behaviour, please contact me, I'm very interested